# How to reload phonegap index.html file on notification click

Tags: android, cordova

I done an android application using Phonegap and Java. I got notification successfully in application , after clicking notification app is start from background.I want to reload my Index.html file after notification click. How can i handle this issue ?
Please help
thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using this plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/ ?? any framework?  or simple?

Comment: No, traditional Java notification

Comment: document.location = "index.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks mit, here is my generate notification code

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
  context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("data1", "data1");
    MainActivity ObjMain=new MainActivity();
    ObjMain.sendJavascript("TestFunc");
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    PendingIntent contentIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    if (message!="")
    {        
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```